# Dealing with arbitrarily long paragraphs

Tags: line-breaking

We deal with arbitrary user input. From time to time, users push the limits of our LaTeX server by submitting arbitrarily long paragraphs: hundreds of pages of text, which has spaces, but no linebreaks.

This hogs resources and eventually leads to us timing the job out.

I read in “Breaking Paragraphs Into Lines” (Knuth & Plass 1981):

> ...arbitrarily long paragraphs can be handled if we make a minor change suggested by Cooper<sup>33</sup>: When the number of words in a given paragraph exceeds some maximum number n<sub>max</sub>,apply the method to the first n<sub>max</sub> words; then output all but the final line and resume the method again, beginning with the copy carried over from the line that was not output.
>
> <sup>33</sup>P. I. Cooper, ‘The influence of program parameters on hyphenation frequency in a sophisticated
> justification program,’ Advances in Computer Typesetting [Proceedings of the 1966 International Computer Typesetting Conference], The Institute of Printing, London, 1967, 176-178, 211-212.

So they have thought about this situation in the past.

I was wondering if LaTeX exposes any control over n<sub>max</sub> (or even implements it at all)? Failing that, is there a good way to handle this case that runs faster, even if we get sub-optimal line-breaking?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `which has spaces, but no linebreaks`? Does it come in as one super long line, or does `no linebreaks` refer to not broken into paragraphs. Because there is a limit as to how long a TeX input line can be.

Comment: Yes sorry we already handle the fact that TeX has a limit on line length. By "no linebreaks" I mean it's all a single paragraph to TeX. So it looks something like `lorem <...many, many words... >ipsum\nlorem <...many more words> ipsum\nlorem...<etc.>`

Comment: "We deal with arbitrary user input." Oh, so you're a teacher, too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no provision for counting the number-of-words-so-far when making paragraphs.

But you can look for James Joyce in the index of the TeXbook. It sends you to page 100, where you find exercise 14.15:

```
\ddangerexercise Since \TeX\ reads an entire paragraph before it makes
any decisions about line breaks, the computer's memory capacity might
^^{capacity exceeded} be exceeded if you are typesetting the works of some
^^{Joyce, James} ^{philosopher} or modernistic novelist who writes
200-line paragraphs. Suggest a way to cope with such authors.
\answer Assuming that the author is deceased and/or set in his or her
ways, the remedy is to insert `|{\parfillskip=0pt\par\parskip=0pt\noindent}|'
in random places, after each 50 lines or so of text. \ (Every space
between words is usually a feasible breakpoint, when you get sufficiently
far from the beginning of a paragraph.)
```

What does the concoction

```
{\parfillskip=0pt\par\parskip=0pt\noindent}
```

do? The group is *very* important!

1. A group is opened;
2. inside this group `\parfillskip` is set to zero;
3. `\par` is issued so a paragraph is produced which will end flush with the right margin;
4. `\parskip` is set to zero in order not to produce undesired flexible glue;
5. a new paragraph is started by `\noindent`, so it begins flush left;
6. the group is closed, so the values of `\parfillskip` and `\parskip` are restored.

The idea, as explained in the answer to the exercise, is that when we get enough far away from the start of a long paragraph, every space between words is a good point where breaking a line, so we can cover our tracks without worrying about the exact placement of the tricky code.

Of course one should define a macro for this:

```
\def\breakhere{%
  \ifhmode
    {\parfillskip=0pt\par\parskip=0pt\noindent}%
  \fi
}
```

The `\ifhmode` is introduced so a badly placed `\breakhere` won't harm. Recommended usage

```
...
some words in the long paragraph
\breakhere
which continues for several other pages
...
```

Comment: Interesting! Could you please explain what exactly this does?

Comment: @Alec Added explanation.